# error al ejecutar ventana en app de android en versiones menores a 7

Tags: java, android, android-studio, api

Tengo problema al ejecutar ventana en aplicacion con android menor a 7 no logro encontrar el error o incompatibilidad 
dejo el codigo logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shop.easy.app.neil.com.solopidelo/shop.easy.app.neil.com.solopidelo.FoodDetail}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                   at shop.easy.app.neil.com.solopidelo.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:37)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                   at shop.easy.app.neil.com.solopidelo.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:37) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                   at shop.easy.app.neil.com.solopidelo.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:37) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1723)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1792)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:999)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:990)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:96)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:1652)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:976)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:18731)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:18607)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:68)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:824)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:73)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:179)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:151)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                   at shop.easy.app.neil.com.solopidelo.FoodDetail.onCreate(FoodDetail.java:37) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

parte del codigo en foodDeatil.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

    //firebase

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    food = database.getReference("Food");

    //init view
    numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
    btnCart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

    food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_description);
    food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
    food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
    food_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_food);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppbar);

    //get food id from inten

    if(getIntent() != null)
        foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
    if (!foodId.isEmpty())
    {
        getDetailFood(foodId);
    }
}
```

codigo xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
         >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:title="Nombre de Comidas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCart"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"


    />


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_name"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Nombre Comida"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_price"
                        android:text="@string/_2_000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="9"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />






                </LinearLayout>


                <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                    android:id="@+id/number_button"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:initialNumber="1"
                    app:finalNumber="20"
                    app:textSize="8sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/food_description"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="@string/descripci_n"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Gracias.!! c;

Comment: Agreaga el codigo del metodo onCreate de la clase FoodDetail.

Comment: Hola Neil, podrías cambiar tu imagen por texto por favor, seria mas fácil de comprender

Comment: si lo deje en imagen y texto

Comment: Si lo vi :D Jaja

Comment: Deberas cambiar los estilos de material desing de la actividad, si trabajas para veriones menores a la 7. eso es básicamente debes cambiar por un equivalente.

Comment: acabo de comprobar que el problema es mi smarphone jaja y funciona correctamente en diferentes versiones de android. gracias por darse el tiempo en responder mi pregunta. saludos!! c;

Comment: @Neil agrega por favor activity_food_detail.xml , porque el problema es tu smartphone, no debería funcionar ahí también? Creo que es lo correcto, para eso son las library de soporte.

Comment: Reinstale la aplicación y se corrigio, pero el problema ahora es que al entrar al activity_food_detail.xml la imagen de fondo background se elimina. ¿por que ocurre?, publico el codigo de inmediato

Comment: @Neil qué cambios hiciste ? Aparte de reinstalar

Comment: solo borre el apk y corri la aplicación por medio de android-studio y se corrigio pero solo que ahora al salir de la pantalla food_detail el fondo de pantalla se borra y queda un color verde. ya agrege el codigo xml

Comment: que versión de android tienes para probar tu app, y cuando respondas a determinados usuarios usa el @ mas su nombre para la notificación por favor, así sera mas facil y se reduce el tiempo de respuesta

Comment: @AshleyG. Desde 5.0 hasta 8.0

Comment: Entonces en términos de diseño de material desing no deberías tener problemas ... Si usas una versión mayor a la 5 mmm

Comment: @AshleyG. si, que mas puede ser, ¿hay algún problema en el código?

Comment: no, en codigo se ve todo bien, a menos que haya pasado algo por alto

Comment: @AshleyG.     me ocurre desde la version 6 en adelante en android

Comment: ME parece que es cosa de los recursos de vectores, mirate https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a
>   null object reference

El problema radica en tu `FloatingActionButton`, primeramente debes asegurar que tu `Activity` extiende de `AppCompatActivity`.

Ahora la definición del tint es correcta:

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

El problema entonces debe ser aquí:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
```

**¿ En realidad estas usando un Vector asset ? , el archivo `ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp.xml` no debe ser una "imagen", si lo abres debe tener la estructura de un .xml.** similar a:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    ... 
    ...
</vector>
```